# Migrar Kohana para Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, kohana

**No bootstrap do kohana eu tenho a seguinte configuração**

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'  => 'myapp',
));
```

Como eu migro ela para o Laravel ?

Pois no Laravel tenho a seguinte url www.example.com/myapp/ e não consigo pegar o css em www.example.com/myapp/css/app.css

`{{url("/")}}` sempre imprime www.example.com **e não** www.example.com/myapp/

**Não sei onde configurar isso no Laravel**

Comment: Qual é a versão do laravel que estás a usar?

Comment: 5.4 é a versão do laravel

Comment: No `Laravel` é diferente o modo de rota, isso com certeza não terá resultado satisfatório como no `Kohana`

Answer (score 0):

Você deve configurar no .ENV que armazenas as variáveis de ambiente
Exemplo:

```
 APP_URL=http://localhost/sub
```

leia mais na documentação 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration